# Is it possible to have a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Currently I have a `UITableView` that uses `UITableViewCell` that displays images from arse.com. I was wondering if I could add another `UITableView` inside the `UITableViewCell` to display an comments.

Comment: Yes, but it's a bad idea unless you disable interaction on one of the tableviews (so that it can't be scrolled by the user). Otherwise the two views will compete for gestures.

Comment: im planning on disableing interaction on the comment table view, how would i go about adding it in?

Comment: Just add the comment table view to cell.contentView in cellForRowAtIndexPath and override heightForRowAtIndexPath so you can tell the cells how tall to be. If that's not sufficient for your purpose you can make a custom cell as you can learn to do by Googling "custom table view cell".

Comment: rschmidt is correct.  Use custom table view cells so that you can display the comments in a  stylish way.

Comment: Why do you think you need a nested table view just to show comments?

Comment: i want to add flag comments button

Comment: So add a UIButton, not a UITableView

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **Yes**

Long(er) answer: ***HELL NO!***

You are just opening an entire can of worms... What problem do you hope to solve by this, that is not solvable by using `UITableViewCell subclass`?